# Does $f_n$ converge uniformly on the interval $[0,0.99]$ or on the interval $[0.01,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Define the functions $f_n: [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ by $f_n(x)=n^px\exp(-n^qx)$, where $p,q>0$.

Show $f_n\to 0$ pointwise. Find $||f_n||_{\infty}$.

So, I have shown that it converges pointwise to $0$ and that $||f_n||_{\infty}=\frac{n^{p-q}}{e}$

So for $p<q$ $f_n\to 0$ uniformly.

I am asked whether it converges uniformly on the interval $[0,0.99]$ or on the interval $[0.01,1]$.

Well, my answer is yes, why wouldn't it? I don't understand why it wouldn't? Anything to help me understand this would be of big appreciation!

Comment: Perhaps the question was supposed to say "where $p>q>0$".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom but for $p>q$ it diverges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be making an error in your thinking. On the interval $[.01,1],$ we have

$$0\le f_n(x) \le n^p\cdot 1 \cdot \exp (-n^q\cdot .01).$$

The right side $\to 0.$ Thus $f_n\to 0$ uniformly on the interval $[.01,1],$ no matter what $p,q$ are.

Now for uniform convergence on all of $[0,1],$ you found that this happens iff $p<q.$ But we just found that on $[.01,1],$ we have uniform convergence no matter what $p,q$ are. The point of this problem is to get you thinking about this.